# Can I add an animation right before the onBackPressed() pops a fragment from the back stack?

Tags: android, android-animation

I tried adding code in onBackPressed but nothing happens even though the debugger shows that the animation code works (which I tested independently as well).

I'm using the support.v4 library for Fragment/FragmentManager and the ViewPropertyAnimator for the animation.

Edit: great answer, I overlooked that you can set custom animations on the fragment transaction. But why does animation code in `onBackPressed()` not work?

Comment: Can you please put your code to explain what's wrong .

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi the code is just a straight-forward fragment that is being added via the support fragment manager with `.addToBackStack(null)` as a part of the fragment transaction

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, just execute this code when you add the fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(fragment, tag)
                    .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
```

your animation is the `popExit` one

Comment: Oh nice, missed this as I was searching with completely wrong keywords. Any way to do it programmatically without using xml animations?

Comment: Maybe you can override the fragmentExitTransition property on your app theme (the xml file which describes the theme). But I've never tried

Comment: This actually didn't work for when I click the back button

Comment: Maybe you cannot use it with the support fragment, the programmatic way works for sure